# xargs cannot find file paths supplied by input file

Tags: linux, xargs

First of all, I am not positive that this belongs here as opposed to ServerFault or somewhere else. If it belongs there instead, I'm sorry.

Anyway, here's some background about my issue. I work for a company that manages various clients' websites and one client we have taken on has a website with a lot of malware that needs to be removed. Now, I have learned a lot over the past few weeks in terms of using grep, find, xargs, etc. to find and perform actions on files that have certain file names, file sizes, and which contain certain strings or patterns of text.

One issue we found is that some images have been injected with malicious exif data (basically, the Make attribute is `/.*/e` and the Model attribute is something to the effect of `eval(base64_decode(...));` where the encoded string is a PHP script that allows the attacker to send a POST request with a certain attribute and then runs the input from that attribute through eval(). And then, they have injected the following code into another PHP script.

```
<?php
$exif = exif_read_data('/path/to/image.jpg');
preg_replace($exif['Make'],$exif['Model'],'');
?>
```

So they are replacing the regular expression .* which matches anything (including the empty subject) with the PHP code that accepts the POST request and executes the given code. In essence, this allows an attacker to execute any PHP code they want on the client's website. All very interesting to figure out, but annoying to fix.

PHP has tools to read exif data (namely, exif_read_data()) and I have used that to scan all image files on the client's website and compile a list of images that have the injected malicious exif data. However, PHP does not come equipped with a way to modify that data. So, I did a bit of research and found that there is a linux program called "ExifTools" that lets you alter exif data. I installed that and ran the following command:

```
xargs -a files_with_malicious_exif.txt exiftool -make="" -model=""
```

The text file there is simply a list of file paths, each on its own line. The script properly reads the filename, because it then ouputs a bunch of "Error: File not found - ./path" messages (one for each path).

The problem is, that path actually does exist, and if I run the following command:

```
exiftool -make="" -model="" ./path/that/does/exist/and/is/in/the/file/like/this.jpg
```

It works. I check the file and those two items in its exif data has been cleaned.

But the number of infected files is rather high, and I would not like to go file by file to run the command on each one.

I have tried to use the absolute path as well as remove the "./" from the file names. I am running from the correct directory for the relative paths to work (as is evidenced by the fact that the second command does work with the relative path) but it still cannot find any of the files.

Is there something I am forgetting to do or am not doing properly?

Comment: Your xargs command looks file and should work assuming the input file is fine.  One caveat: all is fine assuming no spaces in any of the filenames.

Comment: I think you have to provide more information. What's the output of `head -3 files_with_malicious_exif.txt | xargs ls -1`?

Comment: I don't see any spaces in any of the file names (and a search for a space character in my text editor came up empty). @nosid The output of that command `: No such file or directory***.org/**.***.org/web/content/images/****.jpg
: No such file or directory***.org/**.***.org/web/content/images/multimedia/***.jpg
: No such file or directory***.org/**.***.org/web/content/images/***.jpg`

I censored part of the path with asterisks because it would identify my client. Note that the part right after "directory" is appears to be cut off at the start (it is not the full start of the path).

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using xargs, then we can attempt to resolve the issue through diagnostics, if your goal is to simply get the job done, the small little loop below will work;  if you do have filenames that have special characters, you would just need to change the $fixfile to "$fixfile".

```
cat files_with_malicious_exif.txt | while read fixfile; do exiftool -make="" -model="" $fixfile; done
```

Comment: Definitely not set on using xargs. That was just the only thing I had been able to find that would let me run the command.

Comment: So I've tried to run that command and it still can't find the files. I've tried it with and without the leading ./ as well as using an absolute path. I have no idea what the issue is

Comment: Try using "$fixfile"  as opposed to $fixfile and let me know if that makes a difference at all.

Comment: Didn't make a difference, unfortunately. :/ I've even tried using a PHP script with exec() to run the commands, but still nothihng. The image files have 0644 permissions and belong to the user I am trying to execute the script with (i have also tried with root). If I use the `file` command with the path, it shows the path and then "JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01." So the file definitely exists.

I may just end up downloading the images in question and doing the change manually. This issue is taking up too much time. In any case, thanks for the help so far!